# Positioning search icon in Searchbar

Tags: javascript, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I move to TitaniumMobile recently and I need to catch up a lot of things. For now, I want to put "search icon” into left side despite of without focusing. but As with default parameter, it will turn out as below.

```
var search = Titanium.UI.createSearchBar({
         showCancel:true,
         height:43,
         top:0
  });
```

[image]

then, I don’t know how to tinker Searchbar and end up tricking like this.

```
var search = Titanium.UI.createSearchBar({
     showCancel:true,
     height:43,
     top:0,
     hintText:"                                              "
});
```

[image]

But I don’t fond of that way, Is there any other ways around ??

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do something like that ,but you can create a custom searchBar.

Comment: could you tell me how, please ???

Comment: what version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: recent release, 3.30

Comment: @NaingLinAung: This is default behavior in iOS 7, the search icon will be centralized initially and when we tap on the search field given, the search icon will go to the left and keyboard will come up. You may check the contacts app in iOS 7. Still you want to keep the search icon in center you have to create customized search field in your own way.